# JOptionPane.showInputDialog() is called twice, why?

Tags: java

In the showDebugWindow() method inside a class I called, [TinyDebug], the JOptionPane.showInputDialog() is called twice even after I input the correct password, why is that?

Additionally, this code is being executed from an update() method in my Game class, which is called once every second.

Take a look below at the following sets of code for the problem.

**Game:**

```
public class Game extends TinyPixel {
    private static Game game;

    private static KeyManager keyManager;
    private static MouseManager mouseManager;
    private static GameStateManager sManager;

    private boolean isRunning;
    private int targetTime;
    private final int frameCap = 60;

    public Game(String gameTitle, String gameVersion, int gameWidth, int gameRatio, int gameScale) {
        super(gameTitle, gameVersion, gameWidth, gameRatio, gameScale);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        Utilities.printMessage("\t\t-[" + Library.gameTitle + "]-" +
                "\n[Game Version]: " + gameVersion +
                "\n[Unique Build Number]: " + Utilities.generateCode(16));

        ResourceLoader.loadImages();
        ResourceLoader.loadMusic();
        ResourceLoader.loadSound();
        ResourceLoader.loadFonts();

        keyManager = new KeyManager(this);
        mouseManager = new MouseManager(this);
        sManager = new GameStateManager(this);
    }

    @Override public void update() {
        sManager.update();
        mouseManager.update();
    }

    @Override public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = tinyWindow.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            tinyWindow.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
            tinyWindow.getCanvas().requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.clearRect(0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);
        sManager.render(g);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public void start() {
        if(isRunning) return;
        isRunning = true;
        new Thread(this, gameTitle + " " + gameVersion).start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        if(!isRunning) return;
        isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override public void run() {
        isRunning = true;

        targetTime = 1000 / frameCap;

        long start = 0;
        long elapsed = 0;
        long wait = 0;

        while (isRunning) {
            start = System.nanoTime();
            update();
            render();
            elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
            wait = targetTime - elapsed / 1000000;
            if (wait < 0) wait = 5;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(wait);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Utilities.printErrorMessage("Failed to Load " + gameTitle + " " + gameVersion);
            }
        }

        stop();
    }

    public static KeyManager getKeyManager() {
        return keyManager;
    }

    public static GameStateManager getsManager() {
        return sManager;
    }

    public static Game getGame() {
        return game;
    }
}
```

**GameLauncher:**

```
public class GameLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game(Library.gameTitle, Library.gameVersion, 640, TinyPixel.Square, 1).start();
    }
}
```

**GameStateManager:**

```
public class GameStateManager {
    private int numStates = 3;

    public static final int MenuState = 0;
    public static final int LoadingState = 1;
    public static final int GameState = 2;

    public static GameState[] gStates;
    private static int currentState;
    private static String currentMusic;

    protected Game game;

    public GameStateManager(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        gStates = new GameState[numStates];

        currentState = MenuState;
        //currentMusic = Library.backgroundMusic;
        //TinyPlayer.playMusic(currentMusic);
        loadState(currentState);
    }

    private void loadState(int gState) {
        if (gState == MenuState) gStates[gState] = new MenuState(game, this);
        if (gState == LoadingState) gStates[gState] = new LoadingState(game, this);
        if (gState == GameState) gStates[gState] = new PlayState(game, this);       
    }

    private void unloadState(int gState) {
        gStates[gState] = null;
    }

    public void setState(int gState) {
        unloadState(gState);
        currentState = gState;
        loadState(gState);
    }

    private void changeMusic(String key) {
        if (currentMusic.equals(key)) return;
        TinyPlayer.stopMusic(currentMusic);
        currentMusic = key;
        TinyPlayer.loop(currentMusic);
    }

    public void update() {
        try {
            gStates[currentState].update();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        try {
            gStates[currentState].render(g);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    public static int getCurrentState() {
        return currentState;
    }
}
```

**GameState:**

```
public abstract class GameState {
    protected Game game;
    protected GameStateManager sManager;

    public GameState(Game game, GameStateManager sManager) {
        this.game = game;
        this.sManager = sManager;
        init();
    }

    public abstract void init();
    public abstract void update();
    public abstract void render(Graphics g);
}
```

**MenuState:**

```
public class MenuState extends GameState {
    private Rectangle playBtn, exitBtn;
    private TinyDebug tinyDebug;
    public static final Color DEFAULT_COLOR = new Color(143, 48, 223);

    public MenuState(Game game, GameStateManager sManager) {
        super(game, sManager);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        tinyDebug = new TinyDebug();

        int xOffset = 90, yOffset = 70;
        playBtn = new Rectangle(Game.getWidth() / 2 - xOffset, Game.getHeight() / 2, 180, 40);
        exitBtn = new Rectangle(Game.getWidth() / 2 - xOffset, Game.getHeight() / 2 + yOffset, 180, 40);
    }

    public void update() {
        if (Game.getKeyManager().debug.isPressed()) { 
            Game.getKeyManager().toggleKey(KeyEvent.VK_Q, true);
            tinyDebug.showDebugWindow();
        }

        if (Game.getKeyManager().space.isPressed()) { 
            Game.getKeyManager().toggleKey(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, true);
            sManager.setState(GameStateManager.LoadingState);
        }

        if (Game.getKeyManager().exit.isPressed()) { 
            Game.getKeyManager().toggleKey(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, true);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        //Render the Background
        g.drawImage(Library.menuBackground, 0, 0, Game.getWidth(), Game.getHeight(), null);

        //Render the Game Version
        TinyFont.drawFont(g, new Font(Library.gameFont, Font.PLAIN, 8), Color.white, "Version: " + Library.gameVersion, Game.getWidth() / 2 + 245, Game.getHeight() - 30);

        //Render the Social Section
        TinyFont.drawFont(g, new Font(Library.gameFont, Font.PLAIN, 8), Color.white, "@nickadamou", 20, Game.getHeight() - 60);
        TinyFont.drawFont(g, new Font(Library.gameFont, Font.PLAIN, 8), Color.white, "@nicholasadamou", 20, Game.getHeight() - 45);
        TinyFont.drawFont(g, new Font(Library.gameFont, Font.PLAIN, 8), Color.white, "Ever Tried? Ever Failed? No Matter. Try Again. Fail Again. Fail Better.", 20, Game.getHeight() - 30);

        //Render the Debug Section
        tinyDebug.renderDebug(g);

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawRect(playBtn.x, playBtn.y, playBtn.width, playBtn.height);
        g.drawRect(exitBtn.x, exitBtn.y, exitBtn.width, exitBtn.height);

        TinyFont.drawFont(g, new Font(Library.gameFont, Font.PLAIN, 14), Color.white, "Play Game [space]", playBtn.x + 10, playBtn.y + 25);
        TinyFont.drawFont(g, new Font(Library.gameFont, Font.PLAIN, 14), Color.white, "Exit Game [esc]", exitBtn.x + 20, exitBtn.y + 25);
    }
}
```

**keyManager:**

```
public class KeyManager implements KeyListener {
private Game game; 

   public KeyManager(Game game) {
    this.game = game;
    game.getTinyWindow().getCanvas().addKeyListener(this);
   }

        public class Key {
            private int amtPressed = 0;
            private boolean isPressed = false;

            public int getAmtPressed() {
                return amtPressed;
            }

            public boolean isPressed() {
                return isPressed;
            }

            public void toggle(boolean isPressed) {
                this.isPressed = isPressed;
                if (isPressed) amtPressed++;
            }
        }

        public Key up = new Key();
        public Key down = new Key();
        public Key left = new Key();
        public Key right = new Key();
        public Key space = new Key();
        public Key debug = new Key();
        public Key exit = new Key();

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) {
            toggleKey(key.getKeyCode(), true);
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key) {
            toggleKey(key.getKeyCode(), false);
        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

        public void toggleKey(int keyCode, boolean isPressed) {
            game.getTinyWindow().getFrame().requestFocus();
            game.getTinyWindow().getCanvas().requestFocus();

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                up.toggle(isPressed);
            }
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                down.toggle(isPressed);
            }
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                left.toggle(isPressed);
            }
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_D || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                right.toggle(isPressed);
            }

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                space.toggle(isPressed);
            }

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_Q) {
                debug.toggle(isPressed);
            }

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                exit.toggle(isPressed);
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private void debug(KeyEvent key) { 
            System.out.println("[keyCode]: " + key.getKeyCode());
        }
}
```

**TinyDebug:**

```
public class TinyDebug {
    private final String appTitle = Library.gameTitle;
    private String tinyPassword, tinyBuildCode;

    private boolean isAllowedDebugging = false;
    private boolean isShowingTinyText = false;

    public TinyDebug() {
        tinyPassword = "test123";                     // - Standard Password (Non-Renewable)
        //tinyPassword = Utilities.generateCode(16);   // - Stronger Password (Renewable)
        writePasswordToFile(tinyPassword); 

        tinyBuildCode = Utilities.generateCode(16);
    }


    //TODO: This method invokes JOptionPane.showInputDialog() twice even after I input the correct password, why?
    public void showDebugWindow() {
        boolean hasRun = true; 

        if (hasRun) { 
            Clipboard cBoard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            cBoard.setContents(new StringSelection(tinyPassword), null);

            if (isAllowedDebugging() && isShowingTinyText()) return;

            String userPassword = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Password to Enter [TinyDebug].");

            do {
                if (userPassword.equals(tinyPassword)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "[" + appTitle + "]: The Password Entered is Correct.", appTitle + " Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    isAllowedDebugging(true);
                    isShowingTinyText(true);
                    break;
                } else { 
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "[Error Code]: " + Utilities.generateCode(16) + "\n[Error]: Password is Incorrect.", appTitle + " Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            } while (userPassword != null || userPassword.trim().isEmpty() != true);
        }

        hasRun = false;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void renderDebug(Graphics g) {
        if (isAllowedDebugging()) {
            //TODO: Render Debug Information.
            TinyFont.drawFont(g, new Font(Library.gameFont, Font.PLAIN, 8), Color.white, "Tiny Pixel [Debug]", 5, 10);
            TinyFont.drawFont(g, new Font(Library.gameFont, Font.PLAIN, 8), Color.white, "#. [Options are Shown Here]", 10, 25);

            if (isShowingTinyText()) {
                String debugHeader =  appTitle + " Information";
                String debugPasswordField = appTitle + " Information:";
                String debugBuildNumber = appTitle + " Unique Build #: " + getTinyBuildCode();
            }
        }
    }

    //TODO: This method prints the [Utilities.printMessage(appTitle + ": [tinyPassword] Generated and Stored @ FilePath: \n" + logFile.getAbsolutePath());] twice, why?
    private void writePasswordToFile(String tinyPassword) {
        BufferedWriter bWriter = null;
        try {
            File logFile = new File("tinyPassword.txt");

            Utilities.printMessage(appTitle + ": [tinyPassword] Generated and Stored @ FilePath: \n" + logFile.getAbsolutePath());

            bWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile));
            bWriter.write(appTitle + " debug Password: " + tinyPassword);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Utilities.printErrorMessage("Failed to Write [tinyPassword] to File.");
        } finally {
            try {
                bWriter.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Utilities.printErrorMessage("Failed to Close [bWriter] Object.");
            }
        }
    }

    public String getTinyPassword() {
        return tinyPassword;
    }

    public String getTinyBuildCode() {
        return tinyBuildCode;
    }

    public void isShowingTinyText(boolean isShowingTinyText) {
        this.isShowingTinyText = isShowingTinyText;
    }

    public boolean isShowingTinyText() {
        return isShowingTinyText;
    }

    public void isAllowedDebugging(boolean isAllowedDebugging) {
        this.isAllowedDebugging = isAllowedDebugging;

        if (isAllowedDebugging) showDebugWindow();
    }

    public boolean isAllowedDebugging() {
        return isAllowedDebugging;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*Additionally, this code is being executed from an update() method in my Game class, which is called once every second.*" You are popping up a dialog every 1 second? That is really annoying.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think, the reason is, when showDebugWindow() gets called, while you type your password, one more second elapse(you can't enter your pass fast enough), and system call the method again.

Comment: @user1803551 I am doing that because I have to check keyboard input.

Comment: Calling this method every 1 second has nothing to do with checking input. Post the MCVE if you want real help.

Comment: A better way to check keyboard input would be using Event Driven Programming which is one of the most strong part of Java. For example, if you want to track keyboard events, you can attach a KeyListener to a component, and then whenever a KeyEvent occurs, it fires an event to notify you.

Comment: @Saibot True, and I have that implemented in a keyManager class. I'll add the code to that class to my question so you can take a look. I'll also add the part of the code where this action is firing.

Comment: I can't find showDebugWindow() call for 10 mins :) can you point?

Comment: @Saibot sure, go to TinyDebug > showDebugWindow(). The first method under the TinyDebug constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In showDebugWindow() method, you have this statement:

```
if (userPassword.equals(tinyPassword)) {
                ...
                isAllowedDebugging(true); // Problematic statement
                ...
            }
```

Which calls this method:

```
public void isAllowedDebugging(boolean isAllowedDebugging) {
    this.isAllowedDebugging = isAllowedDebugging;

    if (isAllowedDebugging) showDebugWindow(); // Second call?
}
```

As you see, when you set isAllowedDebugging switch, you also call the method, so when you enter password correct, this second call happens.

Comment: So you mean, make a variable at the beginning of the method, hasRun, and set that to true?Then at the end of the method set that to false. Then place the logic of the method inside an if else, checking to see if the hasRun variable is true or false.

Comment: Exactly. This ensures that you won't call the method again until the call returns.

Comment: The logic makes sense on that, however, when executed, the problem still occurs.

Comment: In this project, I am not. I have one thread acting as the whole game. Thus, when you start the game, this thread is created, when you exit, the thread is destroyed.

Comment: But you use syncronized methods, why? If your program is not concurrent, syncronized methods are unnecessary

Comment: True, I should just get rid of the synchronized part.

Comment: @NicholasAdamou I changed the answer, problem is something else. Please check.

Comment: @salbot lol, I had this before your first answer, so what must have fixed the problem was getting rid of the line you indicated here, and adding the boolean var hasRun and resetting at the end of the showDebugWindow(). Thanks for your help with this problem, much appreciated! =)

Comment: @NicholasAdamou You're welcome :) Please don't forget to upvote too :P

Comment: @NicholasAdamou now? :P